# convert List of List to a single column in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
comments         tags
===============================
Hello I am fine  #askfine #tag1
How are you ?    #ask # tag2
```

I have the below list of lists:

```
[['Hello', 'I', 'am', 'fine'], ['How', 'are', 'you', '?']]
```

Now, I wanted to append the below list of lists as a single column to the original dataframe.

```
comments         tags             processed_comments
==============================================================
Hello I am fine  #askfine #tag1   ['Hello', 'I', 'am', 'fine']
How are you ?    #ask # tag2      ['How', 'are', 'you', '?']
```

How do I do?

`df['processed_comments'] = listOfList` is not working.

Thanks

Comment: `df['processed_comments']=df['comments'].str.split()`

Comment: Hello Anky, Thanks for the quick response. I have a new list of lists and wanted to add a new column to the existing Dataframe.  How do I do? The processed_comments, go through pre-processing and they are not the same as comments.split()

Comment: the `processed_comments` shown is exactly same as `str.split()` , however `df['processed_comments'] = listOfList` should work, when you say its not working what is the problem that you face while doing this?

Comment: If you have a function that does all the preprocessing on comments you can `apply`it like this: `df['processed_comments'] = df['comments'].apply(function)`

Comment: what is the error for `df['processed_comments'] = listOfList`?

Comment: Should work if `df` and `listOfList` are the same `len`. Doublecheck that `len(df)` and `len(listOfList)` align

Comment: agree with @ChrisA , if not try with `pd.concat([df,pd.Series(L,name='processed_comments')],axis=1)`

Comment: @ChrisA - You think `len(df.index)`

Comment: Thanks @ChrisA. Let me check

Comment: Thanks. The problem was with length. Corrected the code and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [['Hello', 'I', 'am', 'fine'], ['How', 'are', 'you', '?']]
```

You can just use:

```
df['processed_comments'] = l
df
    comments         processed_comments
0   Hello I am fine [Hello, I, am, fine]
1   How are you ?   [How, are, you, ?]
```

Each list element is considered a value of the row. So make sure that the length of the list, i.e., the lists inside the list, is equal to the number of rows.